# Dynamically binding ContextMenu items to statically defined MenuItems

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

My application contains a `TreeView` which supports a set of commands, but the commands might move around between menus, only appear on some menus and not others, be shared across multiple menus, etc.

I know the set of all commands that I support at compile time, so in theory I can define a `<MenuItem>` resource with an `x:Key` attribute for each of them in my `<TreeView.Resources>` section.  However, for any given node that is clicked, which menu items that appear can only be determined at runtime.  I can bind `ContextMenu.ItemsSource` to something in my application that returns a `MenuItem[]`, but in order to build this array, I would then need to access the MenuItems that were defined statically back in the XAML file.

Am I doing this all wrong?  Or is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind your ContextMenu.ItemsSource not to a MenuItem[] but a ObservableCollection < YourMenuClass >. YourMenuClass should contain the header and other parameters you want to bind to, maybe a command. Then use a template to generate your menuitems.

```
   <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemList}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Name}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Comment: When I do this the MenuItem looks funny.  It's elongated, with a significant amount of padding on the left and right side of the MenuItem, and I'm not sure why.   Here's an example of what I get with 2 menu items added.

http://i.imgur.com/O8is6O1.png

Note that the darker highlight rectangle is particularly odd.  It goes away if I hover the mouse outside of the bounds of the darker rectangle.

It's like the ContextMenu itself doesn't know how to size correctly.

Comment: For some reason I had to use a <TextBlock> in the <DataTemplate>, and then it works.  I guess otherwise it puts a MenuItem inside of another MenuItem?  Not sure how it works behind the scenes, but changing <MenuItem> up there to <TextBlock> fixes it.  Although then I have to put the Command somewhere else.  In this case, I got it working by using a <Setter> on a Style for TargetType="MenuItem"

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, but I can't explain this behavior.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130774/12342238) for how to solve the menu item inside menu item problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an Itemtemplate, provide ItemContainer style for context menu. In this way you can avoid the problem of having a Menu item inside another as mentioned in the above comment.

```
       `<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>`
```