# WPF ContextMenu itemtemplate, menuitem inside menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I have the following xaml:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}">
     <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="models:TestItemModel">
              <MenuItem IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Header="{Binding Header}"  />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

The TestItemModel class only consists of a IsSelected boolean property and a Header string property.

TestItems is a list of TestItemModels.

The data is binded to the contextmenu but it is reflected in the UI as a MenuItem inside a MenuItem (with the additional margins as such, making the menu very big). I can fix this by changing the MenuItem inside the DataTemplate to a TextBox, but then I cannot bind the IsSelected anymore (which I need for visualization properties).

There are a couple of questions I have regarding this:

- Why is there a MenuItem inside a MenuItem? This doesn't make sense to me as it's not binded to a menuitem list but to a list of TestItemModels.
- How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because `MenuItem` is the container type and when it translates your view model into visual item it will wrap your template in `MenuItem`. In the same way `ListBox` will create `ListBoxItem` or `ListView` will use `ListViewItem`. To bind properties of the wrapper you need to use `ItemContainerStyle`

```xml
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}">
   <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
         <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
      </Style>
   </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

or, if you prefer, you can do it partially with `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle`

```xml
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}">
   <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
   <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
      </Style>
   </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

In this scenario whatever is in `ItemTemplate` will become `MenuItem.Header` but `IsChecked` property still needs to be bound in `ItemContainerStyle`