# Horizontal stretch WPF ContextMenu MenuItem in HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, contextmenu

I have a WPF system traybar application. When right clicking traybar icon there is a `ContextMenu` using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to get a 2 level dynamically populated menu. It works but the "clickable" part of the items on the 2nd level does not properly stretch to the available width of the parent control. Instead See picture:

[image: Picture of menu where 2nd level items dont fill the parent control]

Now the user has to click the darker section (where the text is) of the `MenuItem` to perform the `Command` of this item. I want the whole of the menu row to be able to to trigger the `Command`.

Here is my XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding Path=Items}" />
<ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="Menu" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="SystemTrayItemsViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TabIconConverter}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" Command="{Binding ToClipBoardCommand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}">
            </CollectionContainer>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" cal:Message.Attach="ExitApplication" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
</ContextMenu>
```

For full source code, check https://github.com/kasperhlund/textgrunt

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I'm having this problem as well but not with the HierarchicalDataTemplate. The problem has something to do with using the CompositeCollection to bind a VM's collection as well as have xaml defined MenuItems.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to this in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130774/1296733).

It seems that the problem is specifying `MenuItem` within the `ItemTemplate`. The `ContextMenu` is apparently wrapping another `MenuItem` around the `ItemTemplate`, causing this nesting effect. Istead, you have to do this via the `MenuItem`'s `Style`:

```
<ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
         <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
         <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ToClipBoardCommand}"/>
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```