# MenuItem with MenuItems from list

Tags: wpf, xaml

The following code creates MenuItems from a list inside another MenuItem. I'm recreating a recent files option but, it is creating a container inside another container when generating the sub-item.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Recent" Height="25" ItemsSource="{x:Static cl_resources:MenuActions.Recent}">
   <MenuItem.Icon>
      <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/MenuBar/list.ico" Height="25"/>
   </MenuItem.Icon>
   <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Click="MenuItem_Recent_Click" Height="25" Cursor="Hand">
           <MenuItem.Icon>
              <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/MenuBar/document.ico" Height="25"/>
           </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
      </DataTemplate>
   </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

This is the [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBd2A.png) that I get, I want to only display what's labeled as 1 and remove the part 2.

I hope the question was clear enough, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `MenuItem` in the `DataTemplate` with StackPanel, Grid or whatever Panel you like.

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130567/wpf-contextmenu-itemtemplate-menuitem-inside-menuitem) asked already. Basically `MenuItem.ItemTemplate` shouldn't contain `MenuItem`. The parent MenuItem creates its sub-MenuItems automatically and sets their content to the specified `MenuItem.ItemTemplate`.

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Click="MenuItem_Recent_Click" Height="25" Cursor="Hand">
        <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/MenuBar/document.ico" Height="25"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I'd seen that answer and have tried before but it gives me an error when parsing the XAML file, in the last line of the stackpanel. I'm thinking that I'll have to fidget with the item source binding.